Set a part of weight tensor to requires_grad = True and keep rest of values to requires_grad = False
I am doing some kind of transfer learning, where I load a dense model and then expand the weight tensor and train only the new values after expanding it and keep the old trained values frozen. in this case I need to set the new weights to requires_grad = True and old weights to requires_grad = False within the same weight tensor. I tried this but it doesnt work:
old_values = weight_mat[0, :, :length[0]] 
old_values.requires_grad = False # 1. I tried this and they got optimized
old_values = old_values.unsqueeze(0).detach() # 2. I tried this in addition to 1 and they get optimized
new_values = weight_mat[:, :, length[0]:]
new_values.requires_grad = True
weight_mat = torch.cat((old_values, new_values), dim=-1)

After I print the number of parameters of models that are not trainable I get 0, I also checked the weight tensor values over epochs and found that all values are updated, whereas I am setting old_values to False.

I don't think you can set different parts of the same tensor to have different requires_grad settings directly. You could use use a backward hook to selectively disable gradients for the old values.

Just to expand on my comment, I don' think you can set different parts of the same tensor to have different requires_grad settings directly. Rather, you could use use a backward hook to selectively disable gradients for the old values. A backward hook is a PyTorch function that facilitates the execution of custom operations while gradients are being computed, during the backward pass. It can be applied to a tensor or a module. When modifying gradients, implementing custom gradient calculations, or inspecting gradients as they are computed, backward hooks are beneficial.
PyTorch supports two primary kinds of backward hooks:

Tensor backward hooks are designated on specific tensors and are invoked when the backward pass for those tensors occurs.
Backward Hooks for Modules: These hooks, which are registered on modules such as nn.Linear and nn.Conv2d, are invoked when the backward pass for those modules occurs.

In your case, you would use a tensor backward hook, which will be registered directly on the tensor (the weight_mat tensor) using register_hook. The idea is the backward hook is used to zero out the gradients for the old_values part of the weight tensor, effectively freezing those values during training.
In Python, the code could look something like this:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, old_length, new_length):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.total_length = old_length + new_length
        self.weight_mat = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, self.total_length, requires_grad=True))
        self.old_length = old_length

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.matmul(x, self.weight_mat)

    def zero_grad_old_values(self, grad):
        grad_clone = grad.clone()
        grad_clone[0, 0, :self.old_length] = 0
        return grad_clone

old_length = 5
new_length = 3

model = MyModel(old_length, new_length)

# Register hook
model.weight_mat.register_hook(model.zero_grad_old_values)

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

input = torch.randn(1, 1, old_length + new_length)
target = torch.randn(1, 1, 1)


optimizer.zero_grad()
output = model(input)
loss = nn.MSELoss()(output, target)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

print("Weight matrix gradients after backward pass:")
print(model.weight_mat.grad)


Thank you for your reply! It works perfectly. But I have a question regarding the functioning of register_hook: It doesnt seem to speed up the training, I noticed that training without hook is faster, so does this mean that the gradients for old values are first computed in the backward pass then zeroed out? In fact, I want training to be faster..

@Safa you're very welcome, I am glad to hear that it works. However, this follow-on question really needs to be asked as a new question on the site. When you do so you can make reference to this thread. In this way, other people will have the chance to give you a good answer. When you do post a new question, you could ping me on this thread, then I can take a look at the new question (I don't have good explanation for what you are now asking anyway - I would need a little time to think about it, which I will do in the meantime.)

Done! Thanks for the clarification,I appreciate your help :) I have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78505110/using-register-hook-to-freeze-a-portion-of-weight-tensor-does-not-speed-up-tra

@Safa Got it, thanks. I see you've already had an answer to your new question. If I can add anything else, I will :)
