Using register_hook() to freeze a portion of weight tensor does not speed up training
I am doing a sort of transfer learning where I want to freeze a part of the weights tensor and train the other, as explained in my previous question
For this, I am using register_hook() to set the gradients of a portion of the weights to zero. I checked that the gradients were set to zero, however, I noticed that this doesn't accelerate the training, it seems that computations still happen for the weights for which the gradients were set to zero and I dont really understand if the register_hook() function sets the gradients to zero after computing them, or computes the new weights with gradients = 0. Is there any way to do that so I can get a similar behavior to requires_grad=False and speedup training?
Here is a simple example:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import time
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

torch.manual_seed(42)

class example_net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(example_net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# dataset example:
class example_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_samples):
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.num_samples = num_samples
        self.data = torch.randn(num_samples, input_size)
        self.targets = torch.randint(0, 10, (num_samples,))

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_samples

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx], self.targets[idx]

input_size = 4096
batch_size = 64
num_samples = 10000

dataset = example_dataset(input_size, num_samples)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

def train_model(net, dataloader, use_hook=False, num_epochs=5):
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)
    start_time = time.time()

    if use_hook:
        def hook_fn(grad):
            grad = grad.clone()
            grad[:, 10:] = 0  # Zero out all but the first 10 columns of the gradient
            return grad

        # Register the hook
        hook_handle = net.fc1.weight.register_hook(hook_fn)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for inputs, targets in dataloader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
            loss.backward()
            #print("after hook:", net.fc1.weight.grad)
            optimizer.step()

    if use_hook:
        hook_handle.remove()

    end_time = time.time()
    return end_time - start_time

num_epochs = 1

# train model without  hook
net_without_hook = example_net(input_size, 4096, 10)
time_without_hook = train_model(net_without_hook, dataloader, use_hook=False, 
 num_epochs=num_epochs)
print(f"Total training time without hook: {time_without_hook:.4f} seconds")

# train model with  hook
net_with_hook = example_net(input_size, 4096, 10)
time_with_hook = train_model(net_with_hook, dataloader, use_hook=True, 
num_epochs=num_epochs)
print(f"Total training time with hook: {time_with_hook:.4f} seconds")


Why would you expect that particular function to speed up training? You don't remove any computation. You still compute the gradient. You still compute chain rule operations with the gradient. Setting a portion of the gradient value to zero adds operations without removing any

@karl that's what I was thinking. But I wanted to check the way it works.

AFAIK, the only way to speedup is to register parameters with requires_grad = False. What this flag does is it stop the creation of computational graph wrt those parameters in the forward pass, so when you have to calculate the gradient, smaller computational graph means faster backward, which give a speed boost. Simply setting grad to 0 does not speed things up (as you still have to backward a full graph and optimizing those zeroed out parameters.
